# r: merge list of unnamed data sets

Tags: r

After importing data from a JSON stream, I have a data frame that is 621 lists of the same 22 variables.

```
List of 621
 $ :List of 22
  ..$ _id              : chr "55c79e711cbee48856a30886"
  ..$ number           : num 1
  ..$ country          : chr "Yemen"
  ..$ date             : chr "2002-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"
  ..$ narrative        : chr ""
  ..$ town             : chr ""
  ..$ location         : chr ""
  ..$ deaths           : chr "6"
  ..$ deaths_min       : chr "6"
  ..$ deaths_max       : chr "6"
  ..$ civilians        : chr "0"
  ..$ injuries         : chr ""
  ..$ children         : chr ""
  ..$ tweet_id         : chr "278544689483890688"
  ..$ bureau_id        : chr "YEM001"
  ..$ bij_summary_short: chr ""
  ..$ bij_link         : chr ""
  ..$ target           : chr ""
  ..$ lat              : chr "15.47467"
  ..$ lon              : chr "45.322755"
  ..$ articles         : list()
  ..$ names            : chr ""| __truncated__
 $ :List of 22
  ..$ _id              : chr "55c79e711cbee48856a30887"
  ..$ number           : num 2
  ..$ country          : chr "Pakistan"
  ..$ date             : chr "2004-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"
  ..$ narrative        : chr ""
  ..$ town             : chr ""
  ..$ location         : chr ""
  ..$ deaths           : chr "6-8"
  ..$ deaths_min       : chr "6"
  ..$ deaths_max       : chr "8"
  ..$ civilians        : chr "2"
  ..$ injuries         : chr "1"
  ..$ children         : chr "2"
  ..$ tweet_id         : chr "278544750867533824"
  ..$ bureau_id        : chr "B1"
  ..$ bij_summary_short: chr ""| __truncated__
  ..$ bij_link         : chr ""
  ..$ target           : chr ""
  ..$ lat              : chr "32.30512565"
  ..$ lon              : chr "69.57624435"
  ..$ articles         : list()
  ..$ names            : chr ""

  ...
```

How can I combine these lists into one data frame of 621 observations of 22 variables? Notice that all 621 lists are unnamed.

edit: Per request, here is how I got this data set:

```
library(rjson)
url <- 'http://api.dronestre.am/data'
document <- fromJSON(file=url, method='C')
str(document$strike)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide example on how you  generated the data ? I did not test the answer but, the following should help. If you can update the Q, on how you came up with the data, I can work to try that.

*update*

```
library(rjson)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
url <- 'http://api.dronestre.am/data'
document <- fromJSON(file=url, method='C')
is(document)
listdata<- document$strike
df<-do.call(rbind,listdata) %>% as.data.table
dim(df)
```

Comment: I tested this out on a sample with a list of lists.  It returns a matrix with the columns/rows swapped. So I think doing `data.frame(t(do.call(rbind,listdata)))` should work.

Comment: updated. that `do.call` method seems to print out the data in the format I want, but setting it to a variable and checking the structure I get a list of 13662

Comment: Try this `data.frame(do.call(rbind,document$strike))`

Comment: is there a solution to get this data frame in an atomic form as opposed to a recursive one?

Answer (score 0):

`purrr` has a useful `transpose` function which 'inverts' a list. The `$articles` element causes trouble as it appears always to be empty, and scuppers you when you try to convert to a data.frame, so I've subsetted for it.

```
library(purrr)
df <- transpose(document$strike) %>% 
  t %>% 
  apply(FUN = unlist, MARGIN =  2)

df <- df[-21] %>% data.frame %>% tbl_df
df

Source: local data frame [621 x 21]

                       X_id number  country                     date
                     (fctr)  (dbl)   (fctr)                   (fctr)
1  55c79e711cbee48856a30886      1    Yemen 2002-11-03T00:00:00.000Z
2  55c79e711cbee48856a30887      2 Pakistan 2004-06-17T00:00:00.000Z
3  55c79e711cbee48856a30888      3 Pakistan 2005-05-08T00:00:00.000Z
4  55c79e721cbee48856a30889      4 Pakistan 2005-11-05T00:00:00.000Z
5  55c79e721cbee48856a3088a      5 Pakistan 2005-12-01T00:00:00.000Z
6  55c79e721cbee48856a3088b      6 Pakistan 2006-01-06T00:00:00.000Z
7  55c79e721cbee48856a3088c      7 Pakistan 2006-01-13T00:00:00.000Z
8  55c79e721cbee48856a3088d      8 Pakistan 2006-10-30T00:00:00.000Z
9  55c79e721cbee48856a3088e      9 Pakistan 2007-01-16T00:00:00.000Z
10 55c79e721cbee48856a3088f     10 Pakistan 2007-04-27T00:00:00.000Z
..                      ...    ...      ...                      ...
Variables not shown: narrative (fctr), town (fctr), location (fctr), deaths
  (fctr), deaths_min (fctr), deaths_max (fctr), civilians (fctr), injuries
  (fctr), children (fctr), tweet_id (fctr), bureau_id (fctr), bij_summary_short
  (fctr), bij_link (fctr), target (fctr), lat (fctr), lon (fctr), names (fctr)
```